# Generating context-free grammar from language

Tags: context-free-grammar

I need to give a context-free grammar for each of the examples:

```
L1 = {a^hb^ka^mb^n : h + k = m + n}
L2 = {a^ib^ja^k : (i = j and k >= 0) or (i >= 0 and j > k)}
```

I've done many simple examples and have improved on my skills to generate CFGs from grammars. I normally start off by solving for the simplest case, then building up from there. However, I'm confused as to where I can start to find the solutions to these problems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about pure CS theory, which is a better fit for cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, imagine peeling off symbols from the outside in. We start peeling off pairs of a and b:

```
S -> aSb
```

If we peel off all the a first, we need to go to a new state; otherwise, if we peel off all the b first, we need to go to a new state; otherwise, if we peel off both at the same time, we can switch over to peeling off the reversed pair:

```
S -> aSb
S -> aXa | bYb
S -> bZa
```

If we end up doing S -> aXa, we will need to exhaust the a on the left in order to possibly accept; otherwise, we can keep peeling off a from both ends:

```
S -> aSb | aXa | bYb | bZa
X -> aXa | bZa
```

Similarly for Y:

```
S -> aSb | aXa | bYb | bZa
X -> aXa | bZa
Y -> bYb | bZa
```

Now for Z, we just need to make sure we end up with the empty string:

```
S -> aSb | aXa | bYb | bZa
X -> aXa | bZa
Y -> bYb | bZa
Z -> bZa | e
```

How would one go about proving this is correct? First, argue that this produces ONLY strings in the language. A proof idea here is to note that the last production is Z -> e and up to that point we've always added the same number of symbols to both sides of it; also, on the left, we could only have added b after a, and on the right, we only could have added a before b. Then, argue that this produces ALL strings in the language. A proof idea here is to describe how to derive a^h b^k a^m b^n in the general case. Consider h < n, h = n and h > n separately, and in each of these cases consider k < m, k = m and k > m separately.

For the second one, your first step should be to split this into two languages and get rid of the disjunction:

```
L2 = A union B
A = {a^ib^ja^k : (i = j and k >= 0)}
B = {a^ib^ja^k : (i >= 0 and j > k)}
```

Now, find a grammar for A:

```
A -> Aa | A'
A' -> aA'b | e
```

Next, find a grammar for B:

```
B -> aB | B'
B' -> bB'a | b
```

Then, write the grammar for S connecting S to either A or B:

```
S -> A | B
A -> Aa | A'
A' -> aA'b | e
B -> aB | B'
B' -> bB'a | b
```

Proof of this is left as an exercise.